# Win32 DLL in C# Program AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

So, I'm having the age old problem of "I changed my code and it didn't work, but then I changed it back and it still doesn't work". We have been working with DLLs as part of an assignment and the instructor gave us the code to play and record sound, which was supposed to be put into the DLL and then used in our own C# program. Yesterday, it worked fine, but then I was trying to figure out if some of my code was redundant, I managed to break it.

Upon calling the startup function `initDialog` from my main program I now get an `AccessViolationException`. I'm well aware that most of the time when you get this issue it is because you are trying to use something that was left uninitialized. However, I don't see anything that should cause this problem in my code, and the debugger doesn't really give me any hints as to what the cause is.

I'll post the code for my `initDialog` function and the variable declarations below and if necessary I can post more of the code later. The idea is I'm creating an invisible window to handle the messages I'm sending so that I don't have to deal with messages in C#.

```
    static WAVEFORMATEX waveform;
    static PBYTE*    pSaveBuffer;
    static BOOL      bRecording = FALSE, bPlaying = FALSE, bReverse = FALSE,
                     bPaused = FALSE, bEnding = FALSE, bTerminating = FALSE;
    static DWORD     dwDataLength, dwRepetitions = 1;
    static HWAVEIN   hWaveIn;
    static HWAVEOUT  hWaveOut;
    static PBYTE     pBuffer1, pBuffer2, pNewBuffer;
    static PWAVEHDR  pWaveHdr1, pWaveHdr2;
    static HWND      myHwnd;
    static TCHAR     szAppName[] = TEXT("Record/Play"),
    static HINSTANCE hInst;

    __declspec(dllexport) void CALLBACK initDialog() {
        WNDCLASS wndclass;
        MSG msg;

        wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
        wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndclass.hInstance = hInst;
        wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

        if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass)) {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows 95/98/NT"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
            return;
        }

        myHwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Record/Play"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

        // Allocate memory for wave header

        pWaveHdr1 = (PWAVEHDR)malloc(sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        pWaveHdr2 = (PWAVEHDR)malloc(sizeof(WAVEHDR));

        // Allocate memory for save buffer

        *pSaveBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(1);

        while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

In the main program I have this code:

```
    [DllImport("RecordDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int initDialog();

    public PlayForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Show();
        initDialog();//AccessViolationException???
    }
```

Comment: Couple of crucial skills you need to learn to get ahead.  First and foremost is certainly source control, *very* important to be able to restore your program to its originally working state.  And you'll need to learn how to debug native code so you can see what statement generated the exception.  All covered well in existing Q+A at this site.  And perhaps ponder a bit about the wisdom of allocating a 1 byte save buffer and registering a window class more than once.

Comment: Beyond the pondering from Hans I was wondering what you expected to happen with while loop at the end.

Comment: @rene The while loop is meant to get and handle messages in the WndProc. In this case I'm using it to get messages pertaining to the play and record functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. The exception was generated by the line:

```
*pSaveBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(1);
```

When I changed the buffer to be a double pointer into a single pointer I made the incorrect assumption that all I had to do was dereference it and then malloc the single pointer. However, I never malloced the single pointer so I could not dereference the double pointer. Adding this line solved the problem:

```
pSaveBuffer = (PBYTE*)malloc(1); //this line
*pSaveBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(1);
```